# Swift: Specialize method of generic class for function types

Tags: swift, generics, overload-resolution

For generic free functions I can use overloading,
to essentially specialize the function for function types, like this:

```
func foo<T>(_ t: T.Type) { print("T is unknown") }
func foo<P>(_ t: ((P) -> Void).Type) { print("T is a function with one parameter") }

let f: (String) -> Void = { print($0) }    
foo(type(of: f))   //  prints "T is a function with one parameter"
```

Note the second version of `foo()` is *not* protocol-constrained,
mainly because as far as I know, we can't make function types conform to protocols
(we can't extend non-nominal types). I could create a `OneParamFunction` protocol,
and could use that in a constrained `foo()`, but I couldn't make all one-parameter
function types conform to that protocol.

But the above overload works without protocol constraints.

Is something like this possible for an instance method of a generic class?

To me, this syntax would seem most natural, but it's not supported:

```
class Generic1<T> { init(_ t: T.Type) {} }
extension Generic1 { func foo() { print("T is unknown") } }

extension Generic1<P>
    where T == ((P) -> Void) {
    func foo() { print("T is a function with one parameter") }
}
```

The "normal" way of creating protocol-constrained extensions on the Generic class
would look like this:

```
extension Generic1 where T: OneParamFunction { ... }
```

but as discussed above, I can't make function types conform to the OneParamFunction protocol.

I also can't just create a single (no overloads / specializations) instance method
and then forward to the free function, this doesn't work:

```
class Generic2<T> {
    init(_ t: T.Type) {}
    func foo() { myModule.foo(T.self) }
}

let f: (String) -> Void = { print($0) }
Generic2(type(of: f)).foo()   //  prints "unknown T"
```

Compiles, but always calls the unknown-T version, I think because of type erasure.
Inside Generic2, the compiler doesn't really know what T is.
Generic2 doesn't define any protocol constraints on T that would help the compiler
properly dispatch the `myModule.foo()` call (and it can't have such constraints, see above).

Using method overloading inside the generic class compiles and seems close,
but still doesn't work, although in this case I'm not sure why.

```
class Generic3<T> {
    init(_ t: T.Type) {}
    func foo() { print("T is unknown") }
    func foo<P>() where T == ((P) -> Void) { print("T is a function with one parameter") }
}

let f: (String) -> Void = { print($0) }
Generic3(type(of: f)).foo()   //  prints "unknown T"
```

Here at the site of calling `foo()` the type parameter of Generic3 is fully known,
so it seems to me that the compiler would have all the necessary type information
to correctly dispatch the call, but that's not what happens, it still prints "unknown T".

Not even repeating the type as a parameter to `foo()` helps (wouldn't be ideal anyway):

```
class Generic4<T> {
    init(_ t: T.Type) {}
    func foo(_ t: T.Type) { print("T is unknown") }
    func foo<P>(_ t: T.Type) where T == ((P) -> Void) { print("T is a function with one parameter") }
}

let f: (String) -> Void = { print($0) }
Generic4(type(of: f)).foo(type(of: f))   //  still prints "unknown T"
```

Do I have any further options?

---

**Update**, in response to Rob Napier's answer.

I think what I wish for here isn't really dynamic dispatch, I'd like to have static dispatch, but based on all the type information known at the *call site*, rather than based on the type-erased value for `T` previously inferred during `Generic.init()`. And that does work with free functions, but not with member functions.

Try this:

```
func foo<T>(_ t: T.Type) { print("T is unknown") }
func foo<P>(_ t: ((P) -> Void).Type) { print("T is a function with one parameter") }

func g<T>(_ x: T.Type) -> T.Type { return x }
let f: (String) -> Void = { print($0) }
foo(g(type(of: f)))   //  prints "T is a function"
```

This does call the "T is function" version of `foo`, even though `T` gets type-erased inside `g()` too. And I think this is more similar to  `Generic(type(of: f)).foo()` than Rob's example with `g<T>()` calling `foo()` (which is more analogous to calling `Generic.foo()` from some other member of `Generic` -- in this case I do understand why `T` is unknown).

In both cases (`Generic(type(of: f)).foo()` vs `foo(g(type(of: f)))`) there are two types:

1. the original type of `f`, and
2. the type returned from the first call (`Generic.init()` / `g()`).

But apparently the subsequent call to `foo()` is dispatched based on type #1 when calling the free function `foo()`, while type #2 is used for dispatching to member function `Generic.foo()`.

First I thought that the difference has to do with how in the above example `g()` returns `T.Type`, while the result of `Generic.init()` is a `Generic<T>`, but no:

```
class Generic_<T> {
    init(_ t: T.Type) {}
    func member_foo() { print("T is unknown") }
    func member_foo<P>() where T == ((P) -> Void) { print("T is a function with one parameter") }
}

func free_foo<T>(_ g: Generic_<T>) { print("T is unknown") }
func free_foo<P>(_ t: Generic_<(P) -> Void>) { print("T is a function with one parameter") }

func g_<T>(_ t: T.Type) -> Generic_<T> { return Generic_(t) }

free_foo(g_(type(of: f)))   //  T is function
Generic_(type(of: f)).member_foo()   //  T is unknown
```

In this case both `Generic.init` and `g()` return `Generic<T>`. And yet, the `free_foo()` call seems to get dispatched based on the full original type of `f`, while the `member_foo()` call does not. I still wonder why.

Comment: the issue I see now with you `member_foo<P>()` function is that there is no parameter to help the compiler infer `P` since we've learned that it does not support "destructuring" function types. *But* I think I found a way to write it so that it prints what you want. I'll let you know ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use more than one generic parameter for your Generic class.

```
class Generic1<P, R> {
    init(_ t: ((P) -> R).Type) {}
}

extension Generic1 where P == Void
{ func foo() { print("T is unknown") } }

extension Generic1{
    func foo() { print("T is a function with one parameter") }
}
let f: (String) -> Void = { print($0) }
Generic1(type(of: f)).foo()   //  prints "T is a function with one parameter"
let v: (()) -> Void = { print($0) } // a bit ugly ;)
Generic1(type(of: v)).foo()   //  prints "T is unknown"
```

But it would be better with [generic type aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62405174/1425697) ;)

## EDIT

So taking your comment into accout I tried to :

1. get rid of the `()`s
2. find a way to scale up the number of supported params without asking too much to the client (that's up for debate though)
3. find a way to use it with non function type

here's what I got:

```
// some generic type aliases
typealias Bar<P, R> = (P) -> R
typealias Foo<P> = Bar<P, Void>
typealias Quux<P, Q, R> = (P, Q) -> R
typealias Qux<P, Q> = Quux<P, Q, Void>
typealias Xyzyy<S, P, Q, R> = (S, P, Q) -> R

// some closures
let fooString: Foo<String> = { print($0) }
let barIntVoid: Bar<Int, Void> = { print($0) }
let quuxStringIntString: Quux<String, Int, String> = { "\($0)\($1)"}
let quuxStringIntVoid: Quux<String, Int, Void> = { print("\($0)\($1)") }
let xyzyyDateStringIntVoid: Xyzyy<Date, String, Int, Void> = { print("\($0): \($1)\($2)") }

// same class as before
class Generic2<G> {
    init(_ t: G.Type) {}
}

// handling any type
extension Generic2 {
    func foo<T>(_ f: T) {
        print("\(T.self) is \(T.self == G.self ? "known" : "unknown")")
    }
}

// these methods are put in an unspecialized extension in order to be "shared"
// I guess if your designing a module you probably won't be able to handle all the possibilities
// but I'm not sure you should anyway.
// it should be possible to extends Generic2 outside it's module to handle custom case though
extension Generic2 {
    func foo<P,R>(p: P.Type, r: R.Type) {
        print("f is a function with one parameter of type `\(P.self)` returning `\(R.self)`")
        print("\(Bar<P,R>.self) is \(G.self == Bar<P,R>.self ? "known" : "unknown")")
    }

    func foo<P, Q,R>(p: P.Type, q: Q.Type, r: R.Type) {
        print("f is a function with two parameter of type `\(P.self)` and `\(Q.self)` returning `\(R.self)`")
        print("\(Quux<P, Q, R>.self) is \(G.self == Quux<P, Q, R>.self ? "known" : "unknown")")
    }

    func foo<S, P, Q,R>(s: S.Type, p: P.Type, q: Q.Type, r: R.Type) {
        print("f is a function with two parameter of type `\(S.self)`, `\(P.self)` and `\(Q.self)` returning `\(R.self)`")
        print("\(Xyzyy<S, P, Q, R>.self) is \(G.self == Xyzyy<S, P, Q, R>.self ? "known" : "unknown")")
    }
}

// you have to create an extension an write an overload of `foo(_:)` for each type you want to support
extension Generic2 where G == Bar<String, Void> {
    func foo(_ f: G) {
        foo(p: String.self, r: Void.self)
    }
}

extension Generic2 where G == Bar<Int, Void> {
    func foo(_ f: G) {
        foo(p: Int.self, r: Void.self)
    }
}

extension Generic2 where G == Quux<String, Int, String> {
    func foo(_ f: G) {
        foo(p: String.self, q: Int.self, r: String.self)
    }
    
    func foo(p: String, q: Int, f: G) {
        foo(f)
        f(p,q)
    }
}

extension Generic2 where G == Quux<String, Int, Void> {
    func foo(_ f: G) {
        foo(p: String.self, q: Int.self, r: Void.self)
    }
    
    func foo(p: String, q: Int, f: G) {
        foo(f)
        f(p,q)
    }
}
```

I tested it like that :

```
print("fooString:")
Generic2(Foo<String>.self).foo(fooString)

print("\nbarIntVoid:")
Generic2(Bar<Int, Void>.self).foo(barIntVoid)

print("\nquuxStringIntString:")
Generic2(Quux<String, Int, String>.self).foo(quuxStringIntString)

print("\nquuxStringIntString:")
Generic2(Quux<String, Int, Void>.self).foo(quuxStringIntString)

print("\nquuxStringIntVoid:")
Generic2(Quux<String, Int, Void>.self).foo(p: "#", q:1, f: quuxStringIntVoid) // prints "#1"

print("\nxyzyyDateStringIntVoid:")
Generic2(Xyzyy<Date, String, Int, Void>.self).foo(xyzyyDateStringIntVoid)

print("\nnon function types:")
Generic2(Foo<String>.self).foo(Int.self)
Generic2(Foo<String>.self).foo(1)
Generic2(Int.self).foo(1)
```

and the output looks like that :

```
fooString:
f is a function with one parameter of type `String` returning `()`
(String) -> () is known

barIntVoid:
f is a function with one parameter of type `Int` returning `()`
(Int) -> () is known

quuxStringIntString:
f is a function with two parameter of type `String` and `Int` returning `String`
(String, Int) -> String is known

quuxStringIntString:
(String, Int) -> String is unknown

quuxStringIntVoid:
f is a function with two parameter of type `String` and `Int` returning `()`
(String, Int) -> () is known
#1

xyzyyDateStringIntVoid:
(Date, String, Int) -> () is known

non function types:
Int.Type is unknown
Int is unknown
Int is known
```

## EDIT

At this point I'm not sure if I should keep previous edits, but this one is shorter.

I just changed you second overload to :

```
class Generic_<T> {
    init(_ t: T.Type) {}
    func member_foo() { print("T is unknown") }
    func member_foo<P>(_ type: P.Type) { print("T is a function with one parameter") }

}
```

It behavior is unchanged for free_function :

```
free_foo(g_(type(of: f)))   //  T is function
free_foo(g_(String.self))   // T is unknown
```

**BUT** now it also works with `Generic_`'s members :

```
let generic = Generic_(Bar<String, Int>.self)
generic.member_foo()   //  T is unknown
generic.member_foo(String.self)   //  T is a function with one parameter
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There seem to be a couple of problems with this approach.
1) Requires client code to use special syntax (for `v` in the example).
2) Scaling up the number of supported params leads to even weirder client syntax.
3) Not usable with non-function types (`foo(Int.self)` -- should print "unknown T").
With overloaded free functions all these problems can be avoided, natural syntax works for all types.

Comment: As I said it would be better with generic type aliases

Comment: FYI I'm still playing with the compiler and will update my answer if I find something. I'm not really sure what your trying to do though, and maybe you already have a solution that works for you. I just enjoy the challenge :)

Comment: Well, my solution for now is to use free functions :) . But this leads to somewhat uglier client syntax (`foo(bar(create(x)))` instead of `create(x).foo().bar()`. The use case is basically registering Swift methods so that later they can be called based on strings received from script or network. Something like `export(MyClass.foo, as: "foo")`. In more complicated cases (eg. when a param of the exported method is a callback func), we'd need some follow-up: `export(...).doStuff()`, but because of the issues in the questions, I need to make `doStuff` a free function, which is a bit weird.

Comment: I totally agree, free function are uglier, generics on the other hand are lovely ;)

Comment: @imre I was wondering, did you see my last edit burried at the bottom of my post, and did it help you ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of, but what you're doing doesn't really work the way you likely intend it to, and other solutions will fail in similar ways that basically make it useless.

First, let's skip to the answer you're looking for (but won't do what you probably want). Your problem is just syntax. Swift doesn't support this syntax:

```
extension Generic1<P>
    where T == ((P) -> Void) {
    func foo() { print("T is a function with one parameter") }
}
```

Instead you write it this way:

```
extension Generic1
{
    func foo<P>() where T == ((P) -> Void) { print("T is a function with one parameter") }
}
```

As I said, this is just syntax. It's nothing deep, and Swift may improve this later. But what you're trying to do *is* deep, and broken. Overloading this way does not make static things dynamic. Specializations like this must never change semantics, because you can't be certain which will be called. For example, using your top-level functions:

```
func g<T>(_ x: T) {
    foo(type(of: x))
}

g(1) // T is unknown
g(f) // T is unknown
```

The problem is that `g` resolves `foo` in the context of "T can be any type at all." In that context, it selects your "unknown" case. That's determined at compile-time, based on the best information available. If the compiler can prove that `T` is `(P) -> Void`, then it will select the other overload, but it can't prove that here. Worst, if the compiler improves in the future, it might call the other function.

The point of ambiguous overloads like this is optimization, not a replacement for class-based inheritance. For example, some algorithms are possible on any Sequence, but more efficient on BidirectionalCollection, so it makes sense to have an overload for `where Self: BidirectionalCollection` to make things faster when possible, but the result must be the same in either case.

So coming back to my original answer, it matches your code, but it won't do what you want:

```
let x = Generic1(type(of: f))
x.foo() // T is unknown
```

Comment: Thanks. I think your `g()` example is something a bit different (I do understand how that works), and what I'm asking about is still static, not dynamic dispatch, the questions is more about exactly what type that static dispatch is based on, and why there seems to a difference in that between the call-free-function and call-member-function cases. Explaining it is too long for a comment, could you please take a look at the update in the question? (Btw. the syntax you said to be correct was already there in the original question as the `Generic3` variant).

Comment: I see the update; yes, that does look like a current compiler limitation. I believe it's this one: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10610. This shouldn't matter, except for performance optimizations, but you're correct that it's a somewhat unintended limitation rather than a fundamental type problem. And for performance optimizations it is frustrating.

Comment: The other area where it can somewhat matter is API syntax. In a similar (but more complicated) scenario I can now support syntax like `foo(bar(create()))`, but not the more natural `create().foo().bar()`. Not a huge problem, I was just curious about the reasons behind it. Thanks for the clarification.