# Swift: generic overloads, definition of "more specialized"

Tags: swift, generics, overload-resolution

In the below example, why is the `foo(f)` call ambiguous?
I understand that the second overload could also apply with `P == ()`,
but why isn't the first one considered more specialized,
and therefore a better match?

```
func foo<R>(_ f: () -> R) { print("r") }
func foo<P, R>(_ f: (P) -> R) { print("pr") }

let f: () -> Int = { 42 }
foo(f)   //  "Ambiguous use of 'foo'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your problem is that you don't [**explicitely**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45184498/1425697) tell the compiler that `P == ()`

try the following code in a playground :

```
Void.self == (Void).self // true
Void() == () // true
(Void)() == () // true
(Void) == () // Cannot convert value of type '(Void).Type' to expected argument type '()'

Foo<Int>.self == (() -> Int).self // false
(() -> Int).self == ((Void) -> Int).self // false
Foo<Int>.self == ((Void) -> Int).self // true
```

Since `(Void)` cannot be converted to `()`, I guess the compiler can't understand that `foo<R>(_ f: () -> R)` is actually a specialization of `foo<P, R>(_ f: (P) -> R)`.

I suggest you create [generic type aliases](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_typealias-declaration) for your function types to help the compiler understand what you're doing eg. :

```
typealias Bar<P, R> = (P) -> R
typealias Foo<R> = Bar<Void, R>
```

Now you can can define your function like that :

```
func foo<R>(_ f: Foo<R>) { print("r") } // Note that this does not trigger a warning.
func foo<P, R>(_ f: Bar<P, R>) { print("pr") }
```

and then use them with any closure you want :

```
let f: () -> Int = { 42 }
foo(f)   // prints "r"
let b: (Int) -> Int = { $0 }
foo(b) // prints "pr"
let s: (String) -> Double = { _ in 0.0 }
foo(s) // prints "pr"
```

But you can actually just write :

```
func foo<R>(_ f: (()) -> R) { print("r") }
func foo<P, R>(_ f: (P) -> R) { print("pr") }
```

or even :

```
func foo<R>(_ f: (Void) -> R) { print("r") } // triggers warning :
// When calling this function in Swift 4 or later, you must pass a '()' tuple; did you mean for the input type to be '()'?
func foo<P, R>(_ f: (P) -> R) { print("pr") }
```

and you get the same results.

Comment: Oh, nice. The key insight I was missing is `(P0..Pn) -> R` vs `((P0..Pn)) -> R`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: (Interestingly, the same tuple deconstruction trick doesn't seem to work in a generic class' init().)